# Maximum number of outputs for Azure Stream Analytics Job

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I've had a good look at the documentation and I'm no closer to knowing the answer. Is there a limit to the number of outputs that can be defined for an Azure Stream Analytics job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a limit of 5 outputs, which is currently removed.
Classic portal still shows a warning message when user tries to define more than 5 outputs. It is all but a warning though.
New portal (Ibiza) do not have this warning.

Also current limitations can be found on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#stream-analytics-limits) page.